# Keys falling off from butterfly: change keycap is enough or do i need to change clip?

Tags: keyboard

My "a" and "s" letters' keycaps are falling off. I want to order new ones from the internet, found a cheap solution. The question is: is it enough to buy keycaps or do i need to change the clips too?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Why don't you take it to Apple to be repaired?  Please see [ask] for important info on asking questions here.  Your question is missing a lot of info.

Comment: ...and really it depends on what is broken, the mechanism or the keycap itself. There is no way for us to tell.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the recall program:
https://support.apple.com/keyboard-service-program-for-mac-notebooks